# How to set unchangeable path for log file

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest

I have test files with different nesting level.
For example:

/project/tests/flows/test_flow_1.py

/project/tests/orders/reports/test_reports.py

My setting for log path in `pytest.ini`  is `log_file = logs/tests.log`

But pytest creates the directory 'logs' in each test directory.

Also I tried to set it in `conftest.py` file but then the log file just is not created:

```
def logs_path(request):
    path = request.config.rootdir
    logging.basicConfig(filename=os.path.join(path, 'tests.log'))
```

How can I set this creating only one time in the root project directory?

Comment: How do you invoke tests? At which directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to duplicate your tests with this directory structure:

```
├── flow
│   └── test_flow.py
├── logs
│   └── my.log
├── orders
│   └── reports
│       └── test_reports.py
└── pytest.ini
```

pytest.ini:

```
[pytest]
log_cli = 1
log_cli_level = INFO
log_file = logs/my.log
log_file_level = DEBUG
```

At the level where `pyest.ini` is, I invoke pytest:

```bash
$ pytest
...
collected 2 items

flow/test_flow.py::test_flow
------------------------------------ live log call -------------------------------------
INFO     root:test_flow.py:3 in test flow
PASSED                                                                           [ 50%]
orders/reports/test_reports.py::test_reports
------------------------------------ live log call -------------------------------------
INFO     root:test_reports.py:5 in test reports
PASSED                                                                           [100%]

================================== 2 passed in 0.01s ===================================
```

With these settings, I only see a single `logs/my.log` file and its content is:

```
INFO     root:test_flow.py:3 in test flow
INFO     root:test_reports.py:5 in test reports
```

Please check your settings, how you invoke the tests, and where you invoke it.

Comment: There was a problem in launching. 
I launched tests in PyCharm interface and it made this from directory of each test.
If launch this from terminal in root directory than all is ok.
Thank's for clue

Comment: I am not using PyCharm, but I think there should be settings somewhere to address this.